# Evaluate: $\sum_{k=1}^{n} x^{\frac{k(k+1)}2},$ where $x\in\mathbb R.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I found this question online. Being stuck, I posted it here for some help! I have only noticed that the differences of indices of $x$ are in A.P. with common difference $1$. Apart from that I'm clueless. Please suggest something..! I have solved an similar question but it was much easier or obvious.. (The question was, evaluate:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{4n} (-1)^{\frac{k(k+1)}2}\cdot k^2.$$ )

But the present question is not easy for me.. So need your help!

Comment: For $0<x<1$ it is definitely lower-bounded by $\frac{1}{1-x}$

Comment: Take $x=\frac{1}2$, then $\frac 1{1-x}=2$ but the growth-rate of the required *finite sum* is very low and it is definitely $<1$. So $\frac 1{1-x}$ could be an **upper bound**!!

Comment: I can't change my comment: I meant upper-bounded, because $\frac{1}{1-x}$ has more terms (your series only has, roughly, every $x^{2k}th$ term

Comment: With CAS I only have: $$\sum _{k=1}^{4 n} (-1)^{\frac{1}{2} k (k+1)} k^2=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \cos (2 n \pi )+4 n \cos (2 n \pi )+16 n^2 \cos (2 n \pi )-\frac{1}{2} \sin (2 n \pi )-4 n
   \sin (2 n \pi )$$

Comment: I have solved this one. As far as I remember the answer is $4n(4n+1).$ But I am not able to solve $\sum_{k=1}^{n} x^{k(k+1)/2}$ though these two are similar(as $x\in\mathbb R$, I'm not exactly sure how to proceed). I guess, we have to consider two cases: when $|x|\le 1$ and when $|x|>1.$ Please suggest something regarding this one.

Comment: It seems that the sum can't be expressed in a closed form. I recently got to know about *Jacobi's Theta function :*  $$\vartheta(z, q) =2q^{\frac 14}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} q^{n(n+1)} \cos[(2n+1)z].$$ Choosing $q=x^{\frac 12}$ and $z=0,$ we find that $$\vartheta(0, x^{1/2}) =2x^{\frac 18}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}=2\sqrt[8]{x}\left(1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{\frac{n(n+1)}2 }\right).$$ But still the limits of the sum doesn't match. Can anyone suggest how to proceed from here, onwards?